# google cloud memcache apis for nodejs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google cloud memcache [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/#Java_Caching_data_with_the_Low-Level_API) provides examples for Python, Java, PHP and Go.. Is there any support for NodeJs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but none that I've seen in the official docs.

It appears there is an experimental package that includes a memcache API in node: https://www.npmjs.com/package/appengine

Other than that, it appears to be a standard memcached instance, for which any node documentation should suffice.

Comment: For those who are seeking answers this package fails with a timeout: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 74.125.202.95:10001

Comment: @ben is there an alternative?